# Cocoa exceptions documentation

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa, exception, documentation

Does anyone know if there is any documentation that describes all the possible exceptions that can be thrown in Cocoa / Cocoa Touch?

I found the Foundation Constants Reference which lists the basic exceptions you might encounter and a brief description of what causes them, e.g.
such as `NSInternalInconsistencyException` or `NSInvalidArgumentException`

but I can't find anything docs for e.g.
`UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistencyException`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such document but a search of the docs for your  UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistencyException example produced a hit inside UIViewController's API reference, which explains exactly what it is. Not difficult at all.